# Update object array values in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have @table_name(object array) contain many objects.
I want to replace its column values one by one with my values..

i have use

```
<% for group_permission in @table_name %>

<%end%>
```

How i change Please help me

Comment: please provide more details. is @table_name an instance of a record inside db with N columns and relative values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi If @table_name is a collection of objects, you can get each as

```
<%@table_name.each do |t|%>
  <%= t.group_permissions %>
<%end%>
```

You also can get attributes as

```
<% t.attributes.each do |a| %>
  <%.......%>
<%end%>
```

Values and names of attributes as

```
a[0]
a[1]
```